# getting only name of the class Class.getName()

Tags: java, class

How can i get the name of the class

```
String.class.getName()  returns java.lang.String
```

I am only interested in getting last part  ie only String

Any Api can do that?

Comment: Java has great online documentation. The page that andyb linked below is an example. Any time you have a question regarding the exact functionality available from a class or package, the javadocs are as easy to find as Googling "java 6 <package or class in question>".

Answer (score 203, accepted):

[`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29)

Comment: String.class.getSimpleName() -> String,    where as String.class.getName() -> java.lang.String

Comment: Thank you, @andyb `getSimpleName()` is easier to access class name minus the package name.
Syntax : `object.getClass().getSimpleName()` [Sample code](http://ideone.com/7E0I6B)

Comment: How to assigned it for static string variable. it showing an error in android studio.

Comment: Does not work for inner classes: This will strip out the enclosing class' name, not just the package.

Comment: @toolforger Maybe that's the desired result.

Answer (score 12):

The below both ways works fine.

```
System.out.println("The Class Name is: " + this.getClass().getName());
System.out.println("The simple Class Name is: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Output as below:

> The Class Name is: package.Student
>
> The simple Class Name is: Student

Answer (score 7):

or programmaticaly

```
String s = String.class.getName();
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: This helped me as i cant use getSimpleName() from my framework ...Tq

Comment: Also, programmatic approach yields sane results for anonymous classes.

Comment: @Imposter you're using something earlier than Java 1.5?

Comment: You need to handle the case where no `.` is found.

Comment: @eckes if the dot isn't found, the result will be -1, adding 1 will give you a substring starting at index 0 - exactly what you need in this case. (I just tested that with `int[]`, the result is `"[I"`.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use following simple technique for print log with class name.

```
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Suppose we have to check coming variable value in method then we can use log like bellow :

```
private void printVariable(){
Log.e(TAG, "printVariable: ");
}
```

Importance of this line is that, we can check method name along with class name. To write this type of log.

write :-  **loge** and Enter.

will print on console

```
E/MainActivity: printVariable:
```

Answer (score 2):

Social.class.getSimpleName()

getSimpleName() :
Returns the simple name of the underlying class as given in the source code. Returns an empty string if the underlying class is anonymous.
The simple name of an array is the simple name of the component type with "[]" appended. In particular the simple name of an array whose component type is anonymous is "[]".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Groovy way of accessing object properties:

```
this.class.simpleName    # returns the simple name of the current class
```

Answer (score -3):

Get simple name instead of path.

```
String onlyClassName =  this.getLocalClassName();
```

call above method in onCreate

Comment: Incomplete solution.

Comment: If you don’t provide the source for the method OP won’t be able to use it.