# How do I get the dynamic class name of an object?

Tags: java, class

So I have a List of Actors and I want to get each Actors dynamic class name. 
For example here is my Actor list: People, Birds, Cows.

I want to get as result the same: "People, Birds, Cows" but without a name attribute in the Actors class. Is it possible?

Example code (here instead of list I used array) :

```java
public Area map[][];
map[0][0] = new AntHillArea();
String name = map[0][0].getClass().getName(); //this results "Area" instead of AntHillArea
```

**Edit**: There was other problems with the code, getClass().getName() works fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If all you need is the name of the class wouldn't: `actor.getClass().getName()` suffice?

Comment: `getClass()` on an object will get it's class. But I'm curious what you need it for.

Comment: No, actor.getClass().getName() only get the name "Actor".

Comment: @user1870865: Show some of your code. You'll get better answers. It is not obvious what you are looking for...

Comment: Code added to the question.

Comment: If `getClass()` returns anything other than the "dynamic classname", then it's not the object you think it is.

Comment: You are plain wrong to state that your example above will return "Area" rather than "AntHillArea".  If you do `map.getClass().getName()` you'll get `[Area;` (IIRC) but the example you give will return the class of the object referenced by the array entry, not the type of the array.

Comment: @user1870865: post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. I used a Animal class, suclassed it with dogs and cats, and put them into an `Animal` array. It always returned the right name. Your example is bad, because it won't compile as is.

Comment: (Though as Amit indirectly points out, your example above will not execute because you never allocated Area.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting only name of the class Class.getName()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777330/getting-only-name-of-the-class-class-getname)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String className = obj.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

**Update:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Area map[][] = new Area[1][1];
        map[0][0] = new AntHillArea();
        String name = map[0][0].getClass().getSimpleName(); // returns "AntHillArea"
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

class Area {

}

class AntHillArea extends Area {

}
```

Use `getSimpleName` method. It gives you only class and will remove any package if having.

Comment: But if I understand this correctly you want me to add this as a method to each of my classes?

Comment: This is not I want. I have added some example to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class Dog
{
    //code
    public String getName()
    {
       return Dog.class.getName();
    }

    //better
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
       return Dog.class.getName();
    }
}
```

And similarly for each class. Or have a global one as mentioned in other answers as:

```
public static String getClassName(Class<?> clas){
return clas.getName();
}
```

To use `Dog dog = new Dog(); getClassName(dog.class);`